# Parallel queries to MongoDB via Async.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async.js

ALREADY SOLVED

I use MEAN stack in my project. Everything was fine. But I have some problem with parallel queries to MongoDB via Mongoose.js and Async.js. 
If I use series method then everything ok.

```
async.map documents, (document, __cb) ->
   async.waterfall [
      (cb) ->
         # some action
         console.log 'first func', first++
         cb err
    ,
      (cb) ->
         db.models.Tags.findOne docId: document.id, (err, tag)->
            document.tag = tag # an example
            console.log 'second func', second++
            cb err
    ], (err) ->
       console.log 'result func', result++
       __cb err, document
, (err, documents) ->
  #have all documents with tags
```

If I have array of the documents more then about 130 items then I see

```
first func 121
second func 121
result func 121

first func 122
second func 122
result func 122

first func 123
second func 123
result func 123

first func 124
first func 125
second func 124
result func 124
second func 125
result func 125

first func 126
second func 126
result func 126

first func 127
first func 128
first func 129
first func 130
first func 131
first func 132
first func 133
first func 134
first func 135
second func 127
result func 127
first func 136
first func 137
first func 138
first func 139
first func 140
first func 141
first func 142
first func 143
first func 144
first func 145
first func 146
second func 128
result func 128
first func 147
first func 148
first func 149
first func 150
second func 129
result func 129

/home/project/some/project/some/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:419
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Callback was already called.
at          /home/project/some/project/some/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:22:31
```

May be Mongoose has a limit of the synchronous queries? Or Mongo? How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Using parallelLimit with a limit like 100 is reasonable? or you need to make it fully parallel?

Comment: Go ahead and post your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. The problem was not in MongoDB. In #some action I have request to other server. The module http (Node.js) opens only 5 socket for connection by default. I've increased this number and everything was fine.